# Any driver for Lexmark Z845?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, printing

Is there a driver for Lexmark Z845 or something compatible with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially there is no support as mentioned [here](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&productCode=&segment=SUPPORT&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1272792471606&actp=search&userlocale=EN_UK&id=RE108).
It is a windows only printer.